# How to lower the resolution of a Remote Desktop session from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows-7, mac, remote-desktop, resolution

I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.2.13 for Mac OS X.  I am connecting to a Windows 7 VM.  When I connect, it sets my desktop resolution to 4096x2048.  This is normally fine, but there are times when I need a lower resolution.  However, I can't change the resolution on the Windows machine (it says "The display settings can't be changed from a remote session") and when I try to edit the settings from Microsoft Remote Desktop there is no "resolution" tab as older answers suggest.  There is a "Display" tab with the option "Fit session to window" which is checked.  I suspect that unchecking this would fix the problem, but it is grayed out and cannot be changed, even when the session is not open.

I also looked under Preferences and found a Resolutions tab, but 4096x2048 wasn't even listed, and when I delete all the higher resolutions it doesn't change anything.

If I try to simply resize the window, it scales the whole window down without changing the resolution at all.

I have read answers that suggest changing the resolution of my local display, or using full screen mode (or both) but I don't want to go that route either because I need all my screen real estate - the typical case for a lower resolution is when using another app on the VM to share my screen (e.g. WebEx, etc.) with somebody who can't see the higher resolution well while I have other stuff on my screen while I am watching what they are doing.

Update: I am attaching a screen shot of the dialog I get when I try to edit the desktop properties.  I was able to get "Fit session to Window" un grayed out, but as mentioned in the comments, unchecking this does not solve my problem.
[image]

Comment: pictures might be helpful here... First, you cannot change the resolution of the remote machine at the remote machine, because you're not using its actual screen; you're locked out of that. The Resolution drop menu of your RDC 'saved desktop' ought to let you change the remote's 'transmitted' resolution, up to the resolution of your local screen [except I cannot test to 4k, I'm only 2k here] Fit to window fits your remote resolution to your local windowed area, so is not going to do what you want. TL:DR Editing your saved desktop >Display tab >Resolution **ought** to be where to look.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added the screenshot and then realized that I am blind... "Resolution" is under the Display tab, not its own tab!

Comment: Glad you got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Tetsujin for pointing out that the Resolution is *under* the display tab, not its own tab.  It is hiding right in plain site.  For the benefit of anybody else who is as blind as me I am including this image which clearly shows the pulldown.  Selecting a resolution from the pulldown and restarting the connection uses the selected resolution.
[image]